# MS CRM 2011 First Connection

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am having a trouble with **Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011**. I would like to get a first connection in C#. I have all information to connect the CRM. I can do this on the browser.

Also I should add/remove a new record (if user fill contact form and press the button, I should add him to the CRM successfully).

Is there any clear and understandable example? I found something that confused my mind.

Answer (score 4):

you can connect to CRM like this:

1. put this in your app-config to the "connectionStrings"-Tag:

   ```
   <add name="MyAppConfigString" connectionString="Url=http://myserver:5555/myorg;Domain=mydomain; Username=myuser; Password=mypassword"/>
   ```
2. this is how to add a contact to CRM 2011/2013

var connection = new CrmConnection("MyAppConfigString");

```
using (var service = new OrganizationService(connection))
using (var context = new OrganizationServiceContext(service))
{
    var contactRecord = new Entity("contact");
    contactRecord.Attributes.Add("firstname", "Peter");
    contactRecord.Attributes.Add("lastname", "Jackson");

    context.AddObject(contactRecord);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

to delete a record, simple use this:

```
service.Delete("contact", myRecordId);
```

to retrieve a record you could use linq:

```
var query = context.CreateQuery("contact");

var result = query.FirstOrDefault(r => ((string) r["lastname"]) == "Jackson");

if(result != null)
{
    var recordId = result.Id;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me more information about `myorg` (service url?) and `CrmConnection`. Is it a must library or something different?

Comment: myorg is the organizationname of the crm-instance. just put your url from the browser. If there is no organization, you don't have to add it. you have to reference these dlls in your project (you can find them in the sdk - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004 ):

microsoft.xrm.client and microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll

Comment: I got it, thank you. So, how can I get `myRecordId`?. simple solution is getting ID column value. is there any different way in CRM SDK?

Comment: CrmConnection is in the Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll.  Please note this was designed for external apps to connect to CRM and was not intended to be used on the CRM server itself.

Comment: I though that he is writing a standalone app or asp.net-website (thats how i understood the question). If he want to create a "Plugin" then he doesn't have to create a connection at all. But even in Plugins I'm usinig this reference because with linq everything is so simple and clean ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would have commented on Tobias Koller's answer, but my low reputation prevent me to do so.

His solution is right, although, it's good to know that in order to test the connection to the CRM without creating any new record you can perform a WhoAmIRequest:

```
WhoAmIRequest userRequest = new WhoAmIRequest();
WhoAmIResponse user = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(userRequest);
```

The returned value should be the user you used for the request.

Comment: should I use it after creating a connection instance like Tobias Koller's answer

Comment: if you want to use the WhoAmIRequest, you have to use it after creating the connection. you need the "service" from the connection to make a request like this.

Comment: Yes. If you want to use this WhoAmIRequest to test the connection, you can replace the piece of code where Tobias is creating the "contact" entity.

EDIT: as Tobias said, you need to use the "service", and not the "context".